# How do we set folder Email Options using Box API V2?

Tags: box, boxapiv2

I am attempting to automatically add upload and delete e-mail notification for user-group for a box folder. The reason I need to do it automatically is that we create several sub-folders programmatically for each project, and only one of the sub-folder should send out an alert when updated.

Basically, this setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, email notifications cannot be set on a per-group basis. Notifications are tied to users rather than groups. Usrs can set their own notifications here (as you point out) or default enterprise-wide notifications can be set under the admin console.